# How can i check condition on multiple columns and put in an particular column of outcome multiple

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, multiple-columns

Hello i need help that i want to check condition that if column BMI > 45 & BloodPressure > 180 & Hba1c_Result > 12 & Rbs_Result > 220 then outcome is True else that particular row is false but it converts all rows on true or false please help me with this!!

```
if df['BMI'].any() > 45 & df['BloodPressure'].any() > 180 & df['Hba1c_Result'].any() > 12 & df['Rbs_Result'].any() > 220:
    df['OutCome'] = True
    print(df)
else:
    df['OutCome'] = False
    print(df)
```

Comment: `df['OutCome'] = df['BMI'].gt(45) & df['BloodPressure'].gt(180) & df['Hba1c_Result'].gt(12) & df['Rbs_Result'].gt(220)`

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe, so that we can copy/paste it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you can use numpy.where() for this.

```
df['outcome'] = numpy.where(((df.BMI < 45) & (df.BloodPressure > 180) & (df.Hba1c_Result > 12) & (df.Rbs_Result > 220) ), True, False)
```